# How can I pass a listview from one form to another form?

Tags: forms, listview

I have 2 forms. form1 and form2. There is a button at form1 for me to access to form2 and in form2, I have a listview2 and some textboxes. I manage to input items into listview2. Then when I click on the OK button in form2, listview1 in form1 should show exactly like listview2. So guys, can anyone suggest me a way to do this? Thanks

Below are my codes. I hope I don't confuse you all.

Form1 code =>

```
namespace MainServerPage
```

{
    public partial class MainServerPage : Form
    {
        public ListView LV;
        public MainServerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddItem Add = new AddItem(this);                //to open form2
        Add.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

}

Form2 code =>

```
namespace MainServerPage
```

{
    public partial class AddItem : Form
    {
        MainServerPage currentform;   //I learn this way of passing form to another but it's not working
        public AddItem(MainServerPage incomingform)
        {
            currentform = incomingform;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(txtCode.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(txtLocation.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(cbxStatus.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(txtWeatherHigh.ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(txtWeatherLow.ToString());           

        listView2.Items.Add(item);      //send to listView2

        txtCode.Text = "";
        txtLocation.Text = "";
        cbxStatus.Text = "";
        txtWeatherHigh.Text = "";
        txtWeatherLow.Text = "";
        cbxZone.Text = "";                     

    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         currentform.LV = load;    //I got stuck here...do not know what to do
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not the list view you want to pass, it's the *data* that the list view is representing. You should probably rethink your design such that you btnUpdate_Click function builds a data object rather than building a ListViewItem directly. Then you can either pass the data object(s) back to your first form.